# 'He went into the room, opening the door using a skeleton key.' Is the time-sequence correct? Is the ‘using’ clause showing method?

Tags: participial-phrases

- *He went into the room, opening the door using a skeleton key.*

Is the *time-sequence* (participial clause describing an event taking place before the main-clause event) correct?

Is the ‘using’ clause showing *method*?

[Grammarly](https://www.grammaring.com/participle-clauses) has an article explaining the use of the present participle clause:

> **Present participle clauses**
>
> A present participle clause can express:
>
> - an action that happens at the same time as the action in the main clause:
>
> Tom lost his keys (while) walking through the park. (Tom lost his keys
> while he was walking through the park.)
>
> She left the room singing happily. (She left the room as she was
> singing happily.)
>
> The participle clause can come first in literary styles:
>
> (While) walking through the park, Tom lost his keys.
>
> - an action that happens just before another action:
>
> Opening the envelope, I found two concert tickets. (I opened the
> envelope and I found two concert tickets.)
>
> - an action that is the result of another action:
>
> Moments later a bomb exploded, leaving three people dead and twelve
> others injured.
>
> When I entered they all looked at me, making me feel uncomfortable.
>
> - a reason for the action in the main clause:
>
> Having nothing left to do, Paula went home. (Since Paula had nothing
> left to do, she went home.)
>
> Knowing a little Russian, I had no
> difficulty making myself understood. (As I knew a little Russian, I
> had no difficulty making myself understood.)
>
> Working as a sales rep, I get to travel a lot. (I travel a lot because
> I work as a sales rep.)

This licenses the ‘opening the door …‘ being placed contrary to logic *after* ‘He went into the room’. But Grammarly doesn’t seem to provide a suitable classification of the way in which the obviously grammatical second ing-clause, ‘using a …’, is used.

Is there a better overall look at the way in which present participial (ing-) clauses are used?

Comment: I believe there is, and though answering one's own question right away is something I am usually very wary of, I see the loss of the material below (originally posted as an answer in a then-closed question) as a worse scenario. This course of action was suggested by a mod.

Comment: I actually answered this question somewhere but wouldn't know how to find it. This: He went into the room, opening the door using a skeleton key. is merely a stylistic alternative to: He went into the room and opened the door using a skeleton key. Also, the comma is really, really important and some of your examples are not this structure....

Comment: I'm not as happy with the 'and' sentence here; there's far more of the 'and then', sequesntial-as-read, flavour, not nearly as evident in the original. Your sentence sounds like there was a second door in the room.

Comment: Whatever, Edwin. Your initial sentence is very different from the others you posted. She ran out the door, singing loudly. That structure is not like your **other examples**. A SVO followed by a present participle clause. They are different beasts.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/613256/2085).

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, ing-clauses may often be used either to describe something intrinsic about the statement in the main clause

('He communicated using a radio' = 'He communicated by radio') (restrictive)

or to tack on additional information

('He communicated, using a radio' = 'He communicated; he did this by radio') (non-restrictive).

But what sort of additional information may be added using ing-clauses? And are there any restrictions we should be aware of?

This 2015 post at [Helping Writers become Authors.com – K M Weiland](https://www.helpingwritersbecomeauthors.com/participle-phrases/) by Eliza Dee has very useful analysis of how ing-clauses are used (note the older 'phrasal' analysis is used) (amended):

> ... [There sometimes seems to be an implication] that, because it’s
> the present participle that’s involved, there’s somehow a requirement
> that the relationship the participial phrase indicates must be one of
> simultaneity.
>
> The problem is, it just isn’t true. ... [T]his supposed rule is not
> now, nor has it ever been a feature of English grammar, descriptive or
> prescriptive or otherwise. I haven’t even been able to find any advice
> along these lines that’s older than a few years, nor any that appears
> in any reliable grammar, usage or linguistics text, and when I asked
> my editors’ groups about it last year, in search of the source of the
> bad advice, none of the members there even knew what I was talking
> about or had ever heard of such advice being given. One did, however,
> point me in the direction of a very dry but extremely
> relevant-to-this-discussion linguistics text, Free Adjuncts and
> Absolutes in English: Problems of control and interpretation, by Bernd
> Kortmann, from which I’m drawing a lot of what I’ll go on to say
> below.
>
> There’s nothing whatsoever technically wrong in a sentence like
>
> - Tying her shoe, Josie heads out of the house.
>
> The fact that the two events cannot logically be simultaneous is not a
> problem. In fact, present participial phrases are what Kortmann
> describes as “semantically indeterminate”—that is, they can mean
> different things, in terms of the relationship between the phrase and
> what it modifies, depending on context. As Kortmann explains, such
> constructions are “unmarked for tense and mood. Constructions without
> a perfect-participial head also neutralize the aspectual distinction
> ‘imperfective/perfective (progressive/non-progressive)’”. That last
> bit means, in linguistics jargon, that present participial phrases not
> only don’t tell us tense, they don’t tell us whether an action was
> completed (unless the perfect participial, eg 'having done something',
> is used).
>
> Moreover, “whether the relationship holding between these
> constructions and the matrix clause [that is, the clause modified by
> the participial phrase] is a temporal, causal, conditional, etc., or
> an adverbial one at all, needs to be determined for each individual
> instance”. So not only is simultaneity not required, but 'temporal' in
> general is only one type of relationship these constructions can
> indicate.
>
> One such relationship is, indeed, [just a basic] **Simultaneity**, but
> there are numerous others, including:
>
> - **Anteriority** ('Sitting down in his favourite armchair, he took out his pipe.')
> - **Posteriority** ('She left her apartment, slamming the door.') –Note that the placement of the participial phrase is what tends to
>   distinguish anteriority from posteriority; compare “He sat down,
>   crossing his legs” with “Crossing his legs, he sat down”–the latter is
>   illogical because no logical relationship between the phrase and the
>   matrix clause, temporal or otherwise, comes to mind
> - **Conditionality** (this one’s a bit trickier to understand, but for example, in a sentence like, 'He was a terrible husband, putting it
>   mildly', the idea of the modifier is something like 'if we are to put
>   it mildly') [a comment clause: a pragmatic marker]
> - **Instrumentality** ('Using the knife, he cut his meat.')
> - **Manner** ('The little girl walked to school, skipping all the way there.')
> - **Accompanying circumstance** ('She stood in the hallway, wearing a red dress'– this is superficially similar to simultaneity, but not the
>   same, as you wouldn’t say “she stood there at the same time as she was
>   wearing a red dress” – it wouldn’t be logical)
> - **Concessivity** (meaning something like 'although', as in 'Knowing the consequences, she broke the rule anyway.')
> - **Causation** ([Hammering the cliffs, the incessant waves finally brought down the famous sea-arch.])
> - **Result** ('He ran very fast in the footrace, coming in second.')
> - **Purpose** [**/ reason** (involving a logical course of action taken)] ('He slowed down, avoiding a person he didn’t want to run
>   into.') (The default reading here is that intent was involved.) / ('He telephoned saying that he was not coming the party.') (Example by @Eglantine; few would argue that this does not address purpose.)
>
> (He telephoned saying that he was not coming the party.)
>
> The examples above are my own [I've given a correct causative, EA],
> but all the semantic categories are from the Kortmann text. ... Of
> course, whether they’re stylistically preferable in a given context is
> a different question, and a much more subjective question....

This is a very useful breakdown of semantic usages of present-participial clauses. I've given it for a complete overview, though the example of the *instrumentality usage* is (apart from the fronting) a perfect match. So an adverbial showing *instrumentality*, not *method*.

Comment: Yes, it's quite nice. I'd say _means_ instead of _instrumentality_, but that's a minor quibble. And note that the distinctions expressed by _causation, result,_ and _purpose_ are very hard to disentangle in practice. Once you get into the realm of thought and judgement, everything gets all blurry.

Comment: I was about to say the instrumentality category seems a bit suspect to me. It looks more like a quirk of *using* that allows it to function as a preposition. If you say something like *hammering at the door, he finally broke through*, that does indicate the instrument or means, but it feels incidental. I'd file this type of sentence under causation rather than instrumentality.

Comment: I go with 'choice of tool' here. The skeleton key wasn't essential per se (a crowbar or sledgehammer would probably have worked). But as JL says, muddy waters. // _A separate question looking at these fine distinctions might prove profitable_ (or not).

Comment: Seems to me there's a difference between the example above (where *using* is acting like *with*) and something like *they got the X ready, using a knife to Y* (where there clearly is a participle clause expressing means).  Even in the second case, though, it seems you need *using* or some synonym. Maybe there are counterexamples, but if not this makes the instrumentality category different from the others.

Comment: One can easily see a difference between 'He eventually solved it using (= by means of) calculus' and 'He painted the sky using (= opting to use) ArtDunce Nacre 21 and 41 Series watercolour brushes.'

Comment: The main instrumentality here is *opening* — not *using*: *He went into the room [by] opening the door.* Then: *He opened the door [by] using a skeleton key.*

Answer (score 0):

A wise person once said: *"You are well-spoken if you are understood."*

For a normal reader, the line makes sense. It feels normal and allows the reader to move on, understanding completely.