# Is there a name for this type of sentence that put together clauses?

Tags: grammar, subordinate-clauses, linking-verbs

I often hear this type of sentence that put together some clauses.

> Maybe because I was running towards you, waving my arms yelling “Don’t do that”.

> DC Police found you naked lying in Lincoln’s crotch covered in nicotine patches with a sign across your chest...

In the first example, there is a subordinating clause that says waving my arms yelling “Don’t do that”.

Is there any name for this linking?
And is there rules for the order of clauses?

Comment: None of these are sentences. Are you talking about what people say in conversation?

Comment: The first is not a sentence.  The second is a poorly-punctuated sentence.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the distinguishing feature of those sentences. This article may help, as it discusses various types of sentence with different clauses. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_clause_structure

Comment: I think you may be referring to participial phrases. _He left the room, frowning angrily_ means that he left the room while he was frowning angrily; generally active _-ing_ participles are intended to supplement descriptions with more information. There are a number of ways they can work; they don't always mean "while".

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['He went into the room, opening the door using a skeleton key.' Is the time-sequence correct? Is the ‘using’ clause showing method?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/559629/he-went-into-the-room-opening-the-door-using-a-skeleton-key-is-the-time-sequ) The different usages of ing-clauses / present participial phrases are detailed.