# Do you need a context to fully understand what a participle clause means?

Tags: participles, participial-phrases

> Having finished the work, he went home.

As you can see, there is no context available in that sentence. So, the above sentence could mean:

1. Because he had finished the work, he went home. Or,
2. After he had finished the work, he went home.

So, I guess you do need a context to unambiguously understand what the above sentence, and other sentences like that one, means. Am I right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['He went into the room, opening the door using a skeleton key.' Is the time-sequence correct? Is the ‘using’ clause showing method?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/559629/he-went-into-the-room-opening-the-door-using-a-skeleton-key-is-the-time-sequ). You're quite right; this sentence is ambiguous, leaving us to guess whether the participial clause shows reason (or licence) or merely  anteriority.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, not really. Thank you for suggesting, though.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, oh, sorry. I didn't read the last part of your comment. I just needed to be sure if I am right. Thank you, that helps.

Comment: As that answer shows, participial clauses have a wide range of implications. They are a tidy way to achieve conciseness, but one has to be careful that this is not at the expense of clarity / completeness. Your example could even be a reduced form of 'He had finished the work, so he could now go home ... which he did.'

Comment: It can only be an adjunct of reason, more precisely an adjunct of implicated reason. It's a construction that has a general circumstantial meaning, but which may  be interpreted in appropriate contexts as giving a reason for the matrix situation.